# Pointers linked list implementation

Tags: java, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

I learnt that java does not support pointers any reason for it.
if java does not support pointers then how linkedlist class has been created ??
and how it works without pointers.
Thank You.

Comment: Pointers are not needed for a linked list. You can make a linked list in Java using object references.  Object o = new Object(); makes o a reference to a new object. A linked list can be built of objects with properties to refer to the next and/or previous item in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Java has *references*, not *pointers.*  The main difference is that you can't do arithmetic with references, but references are perfectly sufficient for linked lists exactly the same as it'd work otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Java reference type is C equivalent to pointer as far as implementing linked lists is concerned , except that complex address manipulations not supported for Java references . Refer [How To Implement a LinkedList Class From Scratch In Java](http://crunchify.com/how-to-implement-a-linkedlist-class-from-scratch-in-java/) to know about linkedlist implementation in Java.